# Defining the argument number in discord.py, sending a picture

Tags: python, discord.py, replit

The problem is on the 10th line, (don't mind the 9th)
I want the discord bot to send back a message with arguments like this ***.../arg1/arg1.arg2.png*** after they send in the command ***!maps arg1 arg2***

```
@bot.command(brief="test")
async def maps(ctx, *args):
    if not args:
        await ctx.channel.send("Nenapsal jsi Rod/ Rod a druh! \nVysvětlivka:")
        await ctx.channel.send(
            "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/661985293834125342/808308254081417227/acz_map_command.png"
        )

    else:
        await ctx.channel.send('Mapa výskytu: *{}*'.format(
            ' '.join(args).capitalize()))
        #await ctx.channel.send('https://antmap.coc.tools/images/{0}/{0}.{0}.png'.format(''.join(args).rpartition("")))
        await ctx.channel.send(f'https://ants-api.qwq.xyz/static/antmaps/{0}/{0}.{1}.png')
        await ctx.channel.send('AntWiki: *{}*'.format(
            ' '.join(args).capitalize()))
        await ctx.channel.send(
            'https://antwiki.org/wiki/{}'.format(
                '_'.join(args).capitalize()))
```

`await ctx.channel.send(f'https://ants-api.qwq.xyz/static/antmaps/{0}/{0}.{1}.png')`
Won't send to the channel https://ants-api.qwq.xyz/static/antmaps/Common/Common.ant.png after receiving the command !maps Common ant
It only does send in https://ants-api.qwq.xyz/static/antmaps/0/0.1.png

Comment: And what exactly is the issue? All you've said so far is that there's an issue - but you've not described the problem.

Comment: `await ctx.channel.send(f'https://ants-api.qwq.xyz/static/antmaps/{0}/{0}.{1}.png')`
Won't send to the channel https://ants-api.qwq.xyz/static/antmaps/Common/Common.ant.png after receiving the command !maps Common ant

Comment: Is there an error message at all? Have you added some debug `print` statements yet? Does the function actually get invoked?

Comment: Yes, the return is: https://ants-api.qwq.xyz/static/antmaps/0/0.1.png

Comment: Right I see - I understand what you mean now and I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your issue now. You're not using f-strings correctly. Replace your send with the below and it should work as expected.

```py
await ctx.channel.send(f'https://ants-api.qwq.xyz/static/antmaps/{args[0]}/{args[0]}.{args[1]}.png')
```

Inside the `{ }` you just put `0` or `1`. Python understands that as literally 0 or 1 - hence the link you're getting. You need to change it so it's actually getting the value you want from `args`.

- [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: Thank you! After more than a year of trying when I had the time, it works!
I also found another way when tinkering with chatGPT: 
`url = f'https://ants-api.qwq.xyz/static/antmaps/{Rod}/{Rod}.{druh}.png'
 await ctx.channel.send('Mapa výskytu: *{}*'.format(
                ' '.join([Rod, druh]).capitalize()))`
while the `async def map(ctx, Rod: str, druh: str = None):`